# Postgresql creating function that dynamically updates foreign key's value based on matching string value

Tags: postgresql, supabase, postgrest

I'm looking for help with my postgresql trigger function that dynamically updates foreign key field based on matching conditions. I believe it's an easy function, but I can't seem to execute it successfully without exceeding stack depth limit (even though the function is triggered on a row rather than statement basis)

Example:

1st table **staff** with cols. id(PK),name,surname,reference_number(string)
2nd table **orders** with cols. id(PK),itemName,price,reference_number(string),sellerId(FK)
for the same of this example reference numbers are identically matching(can't be used as FK as it's hard imported value)

My current function code:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE orders SET sellerId = (SELECT reference_number FROM staff WHERE staff.reference_number = NEW.sellerId);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Thank you for your help & time!

Comment: It is normal that it gets a stack overflow. You are continously setting selleId to itself. Instead of code maybe you should explain what you are trying to do with sample data.

Comment: Going by the same example I've provided, I probably wasn't as clear enough... The reason why I'm looking to link the orders, is so I could use their name from the staff table and filter all the orders that only they have sold, ignoring any other orders that aren't matching their reference numbers. In addition being able to use seller specific fields next to their matching orders.

Comment: Maybe there would be some genius who understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Do not update the same row in an `AFTER` trigger. Rather, use a `BEFORE` trigger than modifies the new tow `NEW` *before* it hits the table.